# Canadian province boundaries in latitude and longitude

Tags: data, latitude-longitude, canada

Are there any datasets available that give a list of latitude and longitude points for Canadian province boundaries?  I don't need anything too detailed as I'm displaying collated data in smallish info graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this for some rough coordinates:

http://www.getlatlon.com/

http://universimmedia.pagesperso-orange.fr/geo/loc.htm

Or, use the Natural Earth dataset:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

Comment: There is Natural Earth v2 now available - [released 18th August 2012] http://kelsocartography.com/blog/?p=4246

Comment: Thanks.  The natural earth data is just what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to find one on geogratis.ca.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Any further pointers as to which dataset on the site would be suitable?  There are a lot of datasets there.

Comment: http://geogratis.ca/geogratis/en/download/atlas.html

Answer (score 2):

The Atlas of Canada Base Maps provide coverage of the entire Canadian landmass. Data elements are feature coded and structurally clean. Base map components are available in four scales and a number of data exchange formats.

1:2 million

1:7.5 million

1:20 million

1:30 miliion

ArcInfo e00 or DXF.

http://geogratis.cgdi.gc.ca/geogratis/en/option/select.do?id=0BCF289A-0131-247B-FDBD-4CC70989CBCB

Download Area [HTTP]

http://www.geogratis.gc.ca/download/atlas/base/

FTP
ftp://ftp.geogratis.gc.ca/atlas/base/

Alternatively
CanVec is likely to be too detailed for you
ftp://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/canvec/